3-degree Galois extensions of p-adic $\mathbb{Q}_p$?
So here is a problem, we need to find out all the non-isomorphism 3-degree Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_7$, and it suffices to find out all the irreducible polynomials of degree 3. It's easy to check whether a poly is irreducible by Hensel's Lemma. But how can I determine whether two extensions are isomorphism?
or you have a better way?

What do you mean "we need to find out...": is this an assignment?
Anyway, it is not necessarily easy to check polynomials are irreducible by Hensel's lemma: a polynomial in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ is not always irreducible if and only if it is irreducible mod $p$. Or did you have something else in mind?
Extensions with prime degree have either $e = 1$ (unramified) or $f = 1$ (totally ramified), and there is just one unramified extension in each degree. Thus each cubic extension of $\mathbf Q_7$ besides the unramified one is totally ramified, and in fact it is tamely totally ramified since $3$ and $7$ are relatively prime.
A tamely totally ramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ with degree $n$ is always of the form $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[n]{\pi})$ for some prime element $\pi$ in $\mathbf Z_p$ and some $n$th root of $\pi$. We can write $\pi = pu$ where $u \in \mathbf Z_p^\times$.  Thus the cubic ramified extensions of $\mathbf Q_7$ are $\mathbf Q_7(\sqrt[3]{7u})$ where $u \in \mathbf Z_7^\times$, so you need to count the number of Galois extensions of $\mathbf Q_7$ having this form.
The question in the title says $\mathbf Q_p$ while the text you wrote mentions $\mathbf Q_7$.  Which is it: $p=7$ or $p$ arbitrary?

we only need to consider p=7,this is my homework, but if there is a solution to all p, i would be appreciated too. and answer your question about Hensel Lemma, i mean when you reduce f by modulo p, f=gh is equivalent to $\bar{f}=\bar{g}\bar{h}$, and you only need to check it whether irreducible or not in $\mathbb{F}_7$, which is quite simple by machine since it's finite?

oh, I see, hensel lemma can be used only when f is coprime with f',and thank for your solution

Yes, when $f \bmod p$ has repeated factors, this mod $p$ factorization does not easily predict what the $p$-adic factorization of $f(x)$ is. For example, $x^2 - p$ and $x^2 - p^2$ both reduce to $x^2 \bmod p$, but the first polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbf Q_p$ while the second one is not.

I will only point out one more thing: when $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ (or really any characteristic except $3$) and $a \in K$, $K(\sqrt[3]{a})$ is Galois over $K$ with degree $3$ if $K$ contains a nontrivial cube root of unity.  Does $\mathbf Q_7$ contain a nontrivial cube root of unity?  (Think about the algebraic formula for nontrivial cube roots of unity in $\mathbf C$.)
